# Execute Deployed SSIS Package from Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ssis

I have deployed a SSIS Package. I'm executing it with a procedure.

```
Exec PushMannualData '0619','Jagri Pharmaceuticals','Yes','INTERNAL\Shaidar';
```

In SSMS, it is getting executed successfully.

I am trying to connect this with ASP.NET to execute. I have written below code in C#:

```
using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsAuthenticationSQLConnection"].ToString()))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PushMannualData", Con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxDate.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownListCompany.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PushProduct", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Session["LoginName"];

        Con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Connection string is

```
<add name="WindowsAuthenticationSQLConnection"    
     connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DATA1;Data Source=SQLSERVER" />
```

But I am facing issue with connection.

The Error is : `System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'provider'.'`

[image]

Comment: Data Source is your server name or IP.

Comment: What exactly is the issue with your connection? What error are you getting?

Comment: @KeithL Data Source is Server Name.

Comment: @mason the error is : `System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'provider'.'`

Comment: At a guess, remove `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;` from your connection string

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid What should be replaced in place of `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1`

Comment: Just try removing it completely

Comment: Did it work ? If so please post an answer with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Nick.McDermaid in comment I removed `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;` From the connection string and it worked.